# Can splitting an ANTLR3 grammar (making a composite grammar) lead to less overall NFA/DFA states?

Tags: java, antlr3

I've run into an OutOfMemoryError while generating a parser with ANLTR3 and the heap space seems to be filled primarily with NFA/DFA states (org.antlr.analysis.NFAConfiguration objects to be precise).

Assuming that:

- the total amount of states needed for lookahead prediction cannot be diminished
  substantially by rewriting the grammar rules 
  (actually: this will be another question)
- increasing the heap space is not an option 
  (because already using a lot and the grammar is only at 60% of its estimated size)

Could splitting the grammar help either because:

- the total amount of DFA/NFA states can be less somehow (don't expect this, really)
- or the amount of DFA/NFA states per grammar will be less and once a grammar
  has been generted, its DFA/NFA states get discarded?

Comment: Is there a possibility of doing some preprocessing?  Is this a language with no reserved keywords?  I can't answer the question about NFA/DFA states, but with more detail about the language I might be able to help you come up with a strategy.

Comment: The language is COBOL, meaning 500+ reserved keywords and some context-sensitive ones too. I've now managed to get memory usage below 2.8G (-Xmx2800M) by restructuring some grammar rules but I fear I will soon again bump into this, since the grammar is only at about 60-70% of its anticipated final size.

Comment: http://koopa.sourceforge.net/ is an open source cobol parser. Looks like they decided to extend ANTLR with island grammars to handle the complexity. Other people have worked on COBOL parsers before too. I recommend checking the antlr-interest email group archives. Good luck.